Using the libcurl library to call the large model API
I followed the suggestion and used the cJSON library to regenerate the data section of the message.I separately constructed the header and data parts in the message initiated by curl, and then used POST to send it out. It indicates that I have not set the model parameter, but I have already set this parameter. Here is my code and the result:
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    CURL *curl;
    char *url = NULL;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    url = "https://api.baichuan-ai.com/v1/chat/completions";

    // 初始化用于存储响应数据的结构体
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    chunk.memory = malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;          

    char *auth_header = "Authorization: Bearer " KIMI_API;
    char *content_header = "Content-Type: application/json";

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, auth_header);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, content_header);

    cJSON *data = cJSON_CreateObject();

    char *messages = "巴黎奥运会中国体育代表团共获多少金牌?";
    
    cJSON_AddStringToObject(data, "model", "Baichuan4");
    cJSON_AddStringToObject(data, "messages", messages);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(data, "max_tokens", 1024);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(data, "temperature", 0.5);

    char *json_string = cJSON_Print(data);
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    printf("%s \n", json_string);

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res == CURLE_OK){
            printf("Response:\n%s\n", chunk.memory);
        } else {
            printf("failed");
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    free(chunk.memory);

    return 0;
}



Here is result:
{
        "model":        "Baichuan4",
        "messages":     "巴黎奥运会中国体育代表团共获多少金牌?",
        "max_tokens":   1024,
        "temperature":  0.5
} 
Response:
{"error":{"code":"model_is_empty","param":null,"type":"invalid_request_error","message":"you must provide a model parameter"}}


I suggest to [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Please copy&paste the output of printf("%s \n", data); and show the code that prints the response.

This is invalid JSON: "  ],\n" You can't have , after the last item in an array or object. You can print the JSON and check it with jsonlint.com.

Don't write your own JSON.  As you've found out, even trivial JSON is likely to have hard-to-find errors in it where you spend many hours trying to figure out what you did wrong.  Use something like json-c, which is available as part of just about every Linux distro.

This is a completely different problem now. At SO, questions are not supposed to be moving targets that get changed every time a problem is solved.

I think the problem is that this line
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

must be changed to
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_string);

And don't forget to release the allocated data. Good luck!
